# Subset xts object with modified index of other xts object

Tags: r, xts

I need to extract a subset from a xts object, `a`, that contains all the dates from another xts object, `b`, plus a set of neighboring dates for each of the dates in `b`. The neighboring dates could be the `n` dates before each date in `b` and the `k` dates after.

For example:

```
a <- structure(c(9L, 10L, 11L, 15L, 18L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 22L, 25L),
  .Dim = c(12L, 1L), index = structure(c(951696000, 951868800, 951955200,
  952041600, 952128000, 952214400, 952300800, 952387200, 952473600, 952560000,
  952646400, 952732800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo"),
  .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC")

b <- structure(1:2, .Dim = c(2L, 1L), index = structure(c(952041600, 952560000),
  tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date",
  tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC")
n <- 2
k <- 1
```

then the output xts object, `o`, should be:

```
o <- structure(c(10L, 11L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 22L), .Dim = c(8L, 1L),
  index = structure(c(951868800, 951955200, 952041600, 952128000, 952387200,
  952473600, 952560000, 952646400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"),
  class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date",
  .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC")
```

I'm getting each date in `b`, and then the 2 preceding dates and the 1 following date. I know that for instance by taking:

```
a[index(b)]
```

I get the dates in `b`. But I couldn't find a way (possibly efficient!) to select the dates next to them.

Answer (score 1):

If you literally meant "neighboring dates", you could add `n` and subtract `k` from each element of `index(b)`:

```
i <- c(0,-seq(n),seq(k))
# repeat index(b) for each value we want: 1) actual value, 2) -n, 3) +k
idx <- rep(index(b), each=length(i)) + i
o <- a[idx,]
```

If you actually meant "neighboring observations", you could take the output from `a[index(b), which.i=TRUE]`, and then add `n` and subtract `k` from each element of that vector:

```
i <- c(0,-seq(n),seq(k))
b.in.a <- a[index(b), which.i=TRUE]
# repeat b.in.a for each value we want: 1) actual value, 2) -n, 3) +k
idx <- rep(b.in.a, each=length(i)) + i
o <- a[idx,]
```

The two approaches yield the same results in your case, but they would be different if `a` didn't contain contiguous dates.